# Numerous .post() and PHP scripts needed for numerous arrays or can it be done in one go?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a .post() request to get a PHP array into Javascript. Example below:

```
$.post("example.php",{"data":user},function( result ){ alert(result);},'json');
```

This works fine with just one array; if the PHP piece ends in just the following for example:

```
echo json_encode($onlyOneArray);
```

The purpose of this exercise is obtain 8 arrays of data from my DB in order to plot a graph. Can I use .post() to obtain 8 separate arrays and differentiate between them? Or do I need to have 8 separate .post() commands and 8 separate PHP scripts?

My PHP script ends in something like the below at the moment. Not sure how to tackle this:

```
echo json_encode($arrayOne);
echo json_encode($arrayTwo);
echo json_encode($arrayThree);
echo json_encode($arrayFour);
echo json_encode($arrayFive);
echo json_encode($arraySix);
echo json_encode($arraySeven);
echo json_encode($arrayEight);
```

Comment: Why don't you make an array of arrays?

Comment: Add the arrays as elements of one parent array, `json_encode()` and send that.

Comment: So this should do the trick? Only the one Json_encode needed on the parent array? $arrayOfArrays = ($arrayOne,$arrayTwo,$arrayThree,$arrayFour,$arrayFive,$arraySix,$arraySeven,$arrayEight);
echo json_encode($arrayOfArrays);

Comment: Im getting a 500 internal server error at the moment with above, trying to solve

Comment: You forgot the word `array`: `$arrayOfArrays = array(...);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
echo json_encode($arrayOne);
echo json_encode($arrayTwo);
echo json_encode($arrayThree);
echo json_encode($arrayFour);
echo json_encode($arrayFive);
echo json_encode($arraySix);
echo json_encode($arraySeven);
echo json_encode($arrayEight);
```

Make a single array containing all the arrays like so

```
$res = array(
            $arrayOne,
            $arrayTwo,
            $arrayThree,
            $arrayFour,
            $arrayFive,
            $arraySix,
            $arraySeven,
            $arrayEight
      );
echo json_encode($res);
exit;
```

Or if you would like to know which array contains which data, give each internal array a name,

```
$res = array(
            'one'   => $arrayOne,
            'two'   => $arrayTwo,
            'three' => $arrayThree,
            'four'  => $arrayFour,
            'five'  => $arrayFive,
            'six'   => $arraySix,
            'seven' => $arraySeven,
            'eight' => $arrayEight
      );
echo json_encode($res);
exit;
```

Of course use more meaningful names for than 'one', 'two' etc.

Answer (score 0):

User **array_push()** function, to push all arrays you want, into just one.
Then in Javascript, you would select each one per index.